# Picture-In-Picture in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am new to compose. Is there a way to handle **picture-in-picture** mode in jetpack compose ? i couldn't find any official docs related to this.

Answer (score 0):

```
    class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    class MyReciever:BroadcastReceiver(){
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
           println("clicked on PIP action")
        }

    }

    private val isPipSupported by lazy {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            packageManager.hasSystemFeature(
                PackageManager.FEATURE_PICTURE_IN_PICTURE
            )
        } else {
            false
        }
    }
    private var videoViewBounds = Rect()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            PictureInPictureTheme {
                /***
                 * video view does't exit for compose.
                 * So we use android view
                 * and in factory we create video view and use apply to assign video.
                 */
                AndroidView(
                    factory ={
                        VideoView(it,null).apply {
                            setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://$packageName/${R.raw.lakshay}"))
                                start()
                        }
                    } ,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .onGloballyPositioned {
                            videoViewBounds = it
                                .boundsInWindow()
                                .toAndroidRect()
                        }
                )

            }
        }
    }
    private fun updatedPipParams(): PictureInPictureParams?{
        return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            PictureInPictureParams.Builder()
                .setSourceRectHint(videoViewBounds)
                .setAspectRatio(Rational(16,9))
                .setActions(
                    listOf(
                        RemoteAction(
                        android.graphics.drawable.Icon.createWithResource(applicationContext,
                        R.drawable.ic_baseline_baby_changing_station_24),
                            "Baby Changing Station",
                            "Baby Changing Station",
                            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                                applicationContext,
                                0,
                                Intent(applicationContext,MyReciever::class.java),
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
                .build()
        } else {
            TODO("VERSION.SDK_INT < O")
        }
    }

    override fun onUserLeaveHint() {
        super.onUserLeaveHint()
        if(!isPipSupported){
            return
        }
        updatedPipParams()?.let {params->
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                enterPictureInPictureMode(params)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(LocalContext.current as Activity)` then call `enablePictureInPictureMode` method.

Answer (score 0):

In Manifest Add

```
     <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:supportsPictureInPicture="true" 
            android:configChanges="screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|orientation"
            android:resizeableActivity="true"
```

In Activity add

```
val rational = Rational(3, 5)
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
val params = PictureInPictureParams.Builder()
.setAspectRatio(rational)
.build()
@comp
 fun pipScreen(){
 Button(
onClick = {
isInPictureInPictureMode.value = true
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
(context as Activity).enterPictureInPictureMode(params)
 }}
```

Picture in picture screen works only in Android 8.0 version(api level 26) and above

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use `ComponentActivity.addOnPictureInPictureModeChangedListener{}`,then you can handle pip mode change in any time :-)

In `compose` I suggest use `DisposableEffect` to work with it